# Hibernate: do not delete child collection on parent removal

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have one of the weird issues that make you growl. I'm having (also weird) Spring/Hibernate application, that is intended to manage database in following way (i've simplified some things, so don't be confused that source code mentions slightly different tables/columns):

```
active_proxy_view table:
id     | entity
<uuid> | <string containing json>

archive_proxy_view table:
id     | entity
<uuid> | <string containing json>

track_reference table:
ref_type | ref_id | track_domain  | track_type | track_id |
'proxy'  | <uuid> | 'example.com' | 'customer' | '123'    |
```

Keeping two tables is mandatory - i need to have both all-time-history/statistical queries and business-value queries only for things that being active right now, so i need to keep set for active proxies tight. `track_reference` table is used for searches so i could do queries like that:

```
SELECT p.id, p.entity FROM archive_proxy_view AS p
INNER JOIN track_reference AS t1 ON 
  t1.ref_id = p.id AND 
  t1.ref_type = 'proxy' AND
  t1.track_domain = 'example.com' AND
  t1.track_type = 'customer' AND
  t1.track_id = '123'
INNER JOIN track_reference AS t2 ON 
  t2.ref_id = p.id AND 
  t2.ref_type = 'proxy' AND
  t2.track_domain = 'example.com' AND
  t2.track_type = 'campaign' AND
  t2.track_id = 'halloween-2017'
```

<sup><sub>(it may be not 100% correct, i haven't raw sql experience in a while)</sub></sup>

And here's the problem:

- Both `active_proxy_view` and `archive_proxy_view` entities are inherited from one class that specifies `@OneToMany` relationship on `track_reference` entity; `@ManyToOne` usage is not really possible, because there are many entities tied to tracking reference
- `track_reference` is managed separately (and this is mandatory too)
- I need to manage views separately from `track_reference` table, but whenever i tell Hibernate to remove entity from `active_proxy_view` table, it takes away `track_reference` entities as well. Even if i play with cascade annotation value, which is blank by default (and as i understand, it means that child records should not be deleted with parent). There is possibility that i've missed something, though.
- I also failed to hack the whole thing using custom `@SQLDeleteAll`, i still can see regular deletes in general log:

  ```
  55 Query     delete from tracking_reference where referenced_entity_id='13c6b55c-f9b7-4de7-8bd4-958d487e461c' and referenced_entity_type='proxy' and tracked_entity_type='agent'
  55 Query     delete from tracking_reference where referenced_entity_id='13c6b55c-f9b7-4de7-8bd4-958d487e461c' and referenced_entity_type='proxy' and tracked_entity_type='lead'
  55 Query     delete from tracking_reference where referenced_entity_id='13c6b55c-f9b7-4de7-8bd4-958d487e461c' and referenced_entity_type='proxy' and tracked_entity_type='source'
  53 Query     DELETE FROM `tracking_reference` WHERE `referenced_entity_type` = 'proxy' AND referenced_entity_id = '13c6b55c-f9b7-4de7-8bd4-958d487e461c' AND 1 = 0
  ```
- I'm using Hibernate 5.2.3.Final through Spring 4.3.2.RELEASE / Spring Data JPA 1.10.2.RELEASE

## TL; DR

So, the question is: how do i prevent Hibernate from deleting associated entities when parent is deleted?

The source code for entities looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class ProxyViewEntryTemplate {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String entity;

    // some other columns

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = TrackRef.REFERENCE_ID_COLUMN_NAME) // 'reference_entity_id`
    @Where(clause = ProxyView.TRACK_WHERE_JOIN_CLAUSE) // `referenced_entity_type` = 'proxy'
    @SQLDeleteAll(sql = ProxyView.TRACK_DELETE_ALL_QUERY) // DELETE FROM `tracking_reference` WHERE `referenced_entity_type` = 'proxy' AND referenced_entity_id = ? AND 1 = 0
    private Collection<TrackingReference> track = new ArrayList<>();

    // setters, getters, hashCode, equals
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "active_proxy")
public class ActiveProxyViewEntry extends ProxyViewEntryTemplate {}


@Entity
@Table(name = "tracking_reference")
@IdClass(TrackingReferenceId.class)
public class TrackingReference {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "tracked_entity_type", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String trackedType;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "tracked_entity_domain", nullable = false)
    private String trackedDomain;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "tracked_entity_id", nullable = false)
    private String trackedId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "referenced_entity_type", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String referencedType;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "referenced_entity_id", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String referencedId;

    // setters, getters, hashCode, equals
}
```

The whole thing is managed through Spring JPA Repositories:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface SuperRepository<E, ID extends Serializable> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<E, ID>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<E> {
}

public interface ActiveProxyViewRepository extends SuperRepository<ActiveProxyViewEntry, String> {}

// the call for deletion
public CompletableFuture<Void> delete(ID id) {
    ...
    descriptor.getRepository().delete(descriptor.getIdentifierConverter().convert(id));
    ...
}
// which is equal to
...
ActiveProxyViewRepository repository = descriptor.getRepository();
String uuidAsString = descriptor.getIdentifierConverter().convert(id);
repository.delete(uuidAsString);
...
```

Comment: Please include the code showing how you are deleting the entity.

Comment: @Naros done, though not sure that it would help much

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `@JoinColumn`, you shouldn't have this problem.

If you need to keep the `@JoinColumn`, you need to remove the foreign-key constraint requirement that gets automatically applied by the persistence provider by changing the annotation to:

```
@JoinColumn(
  name = "yourName"
  foreignKey = @Foreignkey(value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)
)
```

You should then be able to delete the view entity without forcing the tracking references to be removed.

Comment: Sadly, foreign key tweak didn't work. What are my options if i want to try the remove-join-column approach? I'm using Criteria API to build the query like specified in question, and, if i understand/remember it correctly, `@JoinColumn` was introduced in project to allow joins to be made via Criteria API.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a typical shoot yourself in the foot scenario.

Tracking references were updated in a rather sophisticated way:

- Build collection of references to be stored in database (C1)
- Load all present references (C2)
- Store C1
- Delete all references that are present in C2 but not referenced in C1 (using collection.removeAll)

And it turned out that my `.equals` method has been written terribly wrong, returning false in nearly in each case. Because of that, usually every reference was deleted from database (the queries you can see in the log in question), so it was my fault.

After i've fixed that, only `@SQLDeleteAll` query was run - for reasons not known to me, it still acted like if cascade option was set. I managed to get rid of it using `@OneToMany(updatable = false, insertable = false)`; it seems like a dirty hack, but i don't have enough time to dig it through.

I haven't tested it thoroughly yet, but, i hope, that solves the problem.